# how does islam view other religions?

Tags: other-religions

We believe that respect for freedom of religion and conscience is a basic Islamic principle, and we believe that diversity, including religious diversity, is part of God’s divine plan. Moreover, we believe that the salvation of all people, Muslims included, lies with God alone. correct me if i said anything wrong and need more information more answers about how  our islam view other religions?

Comment: Is this a statement or a question?

Comment: So, your question was?